# How to prevent the threading module from slowing down your programs performance in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

When I would click a button on my Tkinter, Python program, the button would freeze and I wouldn't be able to do anything else on the program. The actual command for the button would still work, but the functionality of the entire program went away. To combat this issue, I implemented threading, which in turn fixed the problem. But after I implemented threading, the performance of the program slowed way down.

Does anyone know what causes this? And how I can fix it?

EDIT----------------------------------------EDIT

This is what I tried to do when using the multiprocessing module as opposed to the threading module.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def InitPlaylist(self):
  #code here
def PlayPlaylist(self):
  p = Process(target = InitPlaylist)
  p.start()
  p.join()
```

Comment: The problem, as stated, is that the program either freezes if I don't use threading, or slows down tremendously if I do use threading. So I'm trying to find a way to prevent both issues. I think that the desired behavior is implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain without actually seeing the code, but the most likely reason for the performance hit is the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), or GIL. The Python interpreter isn't thread-safe, so it uses the GIL to protect itself bugs and crashes caused by concurrency issues. The lock only allows a single thread to actually execute Python instructions a time, which means you don't get true parallelism across CPU cores the way you can in other, GIL-less languages. Effectively, one thread executes for a bit, it gets suspended, then another thread can start, then it gets suspended, etc. You still get concurrency, but not true parallelism.

The most common way to fix this is to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, instead of `threading`. The `multiprocessing` utilizes processes for concurrency instead of threads, thereby avoiding the limitations of the GIL. This has some drawbacks, though, since it's more difficult and more overhead to share state between processes than threads.

Comment: What about some of the fairly recently added asynchronous functionality? ([`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), for instance.)

Comment: @jpmc26 async libraries give mostly the same results as threading (without actually using threads), they let you reclaim processing time while an i/o bound operation is waiting.

Comment: I tried using the multiprocessing module, but I when I would use that, it would actually freeze the program after it was initiated. I will edit my original post to show the code of what I was doing when trying to use multiprocessing - or at least the pseudo code, because the program is very long.

Comment: @Hunter it's freezing because you're calling `p.join()`, which will make your main process block until the child has exited. Just call `p.start()` without the call to `p.join`.

Comment: @jpmc As kalhartt said, asynchronous frameworks like `asyncio` or `tornado` are only helpful for I/O-bound workloads. CPU-bound operations still require `multiprocessing` for parallelism, or a C extension that can safely release the GIL during computations (like `numpy`, for example).

Comment: I was given this error after I removed `p.join()`: `[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that. 
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0" after 152 requests (152 known processed) with 5 events remaining. XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)` ---- Do I have to do it in the `main()` function?

Comment: @Hunter yikes! Looks like you're trying to execute code in the child that isn't process-safe. Are you trying to actually update your tkinter widgets in the child process? Or access them from the child at all? If so, that's probably the issue. You can only access the tkinter objects from the main process/thread. You may need to add another edit or even ask a new question with example code that will allow us to reproduce exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Ah, I think I'll just stick with the threading, it seems to work, just slowly. Haha. Thanks so much for all of your help though!